# Error building android project with gradle from terminal

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a simple project `androidproj` which I'm trying to build with Jenkins. That is the reason I'm trying to build it from terminal with gradle. The project consists from:

> 1. androidmodule1
> 2. androidapp1 (androidapp1 has dependency on androidmodule1)

When I execute the cradle by using the following line:

```
./gradlew build --stacktrace
```

I get the following error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file '/Volumes/Storage/Jenkins/jobs/XXX-Android-Compilation/workspace/android/androidmodule1/build.gradle' line: 17
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':androidmodule1'.
>
>   > Ambiguous method overloading for method java.io.File#.   Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null, class
>   >     java.lang.String] due to overlapping prototypes between:      [class
>   >     java.lang.String, class java.lang.String]     [class java.io.File,
>   >     class java.lang.String]

I found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23811315/gradle-fails-with-ambiguous-method-overloading-for-method-java-io-fileinit) and checked that required SDK is installed, build tools are available:

[image]

ANDROID_HOME variable is set:

> admin$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
>   /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx

My gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.androidmodule1"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Locally project started just fine.
Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It turned our that Jenkins for some reason wasn't able to see configured environment variables. I had to go to Jenkins->Configuration->Environment Variables and manually specify JAVA_HOME & ANDROID_HOME paths:

[image]